# Google+ 1.07 Widget not working

Tags: nexus-one, google-plus

I installed the latest Google+ app version 1.07 and now the widget has stopped working, and when I go the widget list, it is no longer listed as a choice.  Has this happened to others and is there a solution?

Comment: The latest version also gives the option to move the app to the SD card. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Is that why it's not working?

Comment: Indeed. Widgets won't work when run from the SD card. However, I moved the app to my phone and I don't see the option for the widget. Either it's a 2.3 thing or they removed it from the app. If the latter then that would explain what you're seeing. Try moving the app back to the phone.

Comment: I did try moving it back.  No widget.

Comment: Then I'd say it looks like they removed the widget functionality, either accidentally or by design. I've not been able to find anything about it in the [Google+ app help pages](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1248781&rd=1).

Comment: For what it's worth, comments on this Google [blog post](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-101-102-103-104-105-106-107.html) have people seeing the same thing as you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets don't work when the app has been moved to the SD card.

When I originally tried moving the app back to the phone to test this, I couldn't get the widget to show up in the list either. However, I restarted the phone and then the widget was available to be used.

So, if you want the widget back, move the Google+ app back to the phone and then restart your phone. If you want to keep the widget, you can't move the app to the SD card.